# Insertion sort array in java

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, insertion-sort

So I made this sortion sort method, all using `for` loops.

I revised it on white board over and over, it looks perfect, however, when I implemented it, it keeps giving me wrong sort, but if I reversed the `if` condition, it will give me the right answer but in reverse, this doesn't make sense!

```java
public void insertionSort(){
    for (int i = 1; i < items.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if (items[i] < items[j]) {
                int temp = items[i];
                shift(items,j, i-1);
                items[j] = temp;
            }
       }
    }
}
private void shift(int[] array, int index1, int index2){
    if (index1 == index2)
        array[index1 + 1] = array[index1];
    else{
    for (int i = index2; i >= index1; i--)
        array[i+1] = array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: which condition did you mean for in reverse it works

Comment: I tested this code in both directions changing the condition - sorting worked fine for input `int[] items = {2, 1, 3, 7, 9, 15, 10, 0};`, ascending order succeeded: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 10, 15]`, descending succeeded too: `[15, 10, 9, 7, 3, 2, 1, 0]`

Comment: I know it is not what you asked but maybe it is related to the confusion... i find it strange that you run j from zero to i here. It gives you a best case quadratic running time. If you run j from i-1 and down, and swap neighbors when items[j-1] > items[j] and break if not, you get a best case linear running time on sorted input, the sort is stable, and you don’t need the complicated shift (swapping neighbors is trivial). The test will be if(items[j-1] > items[j]) {...} which is straightforward

Comment: Thanks for the input, I discovered the problem in my Array class, it simply doubles the array size, my mistake was that I used the array.length instead of count.

Comment: @BWallDev, I meant the if condition if (items[i] < items[j])

Comment: @ThomasMailund I'll try what you suggested, thanks for your input.

Comment: @AlexRudenko yes, my mistake is the Array class, not the sorting code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input, I discovered the problem in my Array class, it simply doubles the array size, my mistake was that I used the array.length instead of count.

```
public void insertionSort(){
for (int i = 1; i < count; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        if (items[i] < items[j]) {
            int temp = items[i];
            shift(items,j, i-1);
            items[j] = temp;
        }
   }
}
```

}